# How to target google map marker using jquery

Tags: google-maps

OK, so I'm simply trying to target a google map marker using jquery, so that I can add some effects and animation to it, but I'm not having much luck.

I tried targeting the (custom) image I'm using for the marker like this:

```
$("img[src*='icon_you']").show();
```

But no luck. I also tried inspecting it in Chrome, but for some reason I simply can't find the output in there, just the map canvases.. :/

Can anyone please provide me with some insight into this?

Comment: are you trying to animate the default marker ?
or trying to change image to google marker ?
Please splecify @thatgerhard

Comment: I already have a custom marker image on there, but I want to animate it when certain events are fired. (Oh I use gmaps.js)

Comment: As a workaround you can create a custom overlay element which will behave like marker - in custom overlays you must specify the html object during creation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays.

Comment: @gawi Thanks so much, that sorted it! :)